# What is the point of Sweetville?

Tags: doctor-who

In the Doctor Who episode *The Crimson Horror*, "only the brightest and the best" are invited to live in Sweetville.

> They go through a "conversion" process. When it fails, it produces the crimson skin that gives the crimson horror its name. When it succeeds, they seem to be placed in bell jars... and that's it.

Why? Was it ever mentioned what they were doing there?

Comment: Isn't this a bit of a spoiler? Or has everybody in the world seen it already?

Comment: @MrLister if you want to edit spoiler tags into it, please do so.

Comment: Although, good point.

Comment: I can't do that... I don't have enough rep to make "minor" edits, and adding a single spoiler marker is too minor.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, it was made quite clear.

Mrs Gillyflower was going to explode her rocket containing poison into the atmosphere, killing the entire population. Then, her converted (ie immune) victims will emerge, and repopulate the Earth without all that corruption and imperfectness.

So basically, it's the plot of *Moonraker*.

Comment: Holy crap, I knew it sounded familiar.

Answer (score 6):

As you'd expect, spoilers are incoming. At the end of the episode,

> the rocket was intended to disperse an undiluted version of the poison used in the conversion process, thereby eliminating all life - probably within a certain area, didn't seem big enough to be worldwide - that hadn't been preserved by undergoing the "conversion" process.

It's essentially your standard "preserve those who are considered "perfect" whilst eliminating corruption, weakness, etc." plot.

Answer (score 0):

Sweetville was where Mrs. Gillyflower and her chosen people would have waited out the poison in the glass jars (which were like cryostasis pods, basically) and then immunized themselves.